# Can I transform the input of a json inside a spring boot controller?

Tags: spring-boot, rest

I have a very simple spring boot web application which consumes requests with json body.

For each json which the application will receive (from any client) I would like to manipulate it as a first step.

For example if the client sends the following body:

```
{
"hello": "world!!!"
}
```

I would like to replace each `!` with a `?`. In this case the result is:

```
{
"hello": "world???"
}
```

This json transformation should be valid for each controller and for any json entering the system.

Is this kind of operation possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may use string.replace to do the same.
Or also you can add custom annotation to manipulate the values of any keys.

Comment: that's not my point... I would like each request will be processed with the same rules without applying for each controller

Answer (score 0):

You can use any replacement methods or regex in your classes.

```
@GetMapping
public String replace(RequestItem item){
// item = item.regex/replacement method
// call your service or whatever
return item;
}
```

When you got the data, you can do whatever you want to do.

Comment: that's not my point... I would like each request will be processed with the same rules without applying for each controller